# Microsoft Access 2010 How to keep Masterform on new record, while Subform is requery

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2010, parent-child

I have a `Masterform`, which is open through a button that goes to a new record. Once the form is open, you must select a `ITEM` from a `combo box`, which is tied to the `Childform`. The `Childform` works perfectly, it loads the data from the `combo box` bound column. But the fields in the mainform, seem to be loaded some data as well. Which wasn't intended.

[image]

As you can see, everything seem normal. But the `Lot No.` a auto increment field, should be set to `(NEW)` or at least the next one to be added. In this case `20`, not 7. I do not want to modify old data, but add a new Lot to a item.

[image]

Comment: how can a child form have a result set when masterform = newRecord?
is your subForm not linked to the masterform?

Comment: @krishKM it is, but I want `LotNo` to automatically go to the newest ID (as if you were adding a brand new one into the database). Its currently going to a random `LotNo` which I dont understand.

Comment: A form will always start/load with the first record. if you want to have an empty record set the form Data properties to "DataEntry = YES"
also try to open the form as "AddNew"